# Text::Balanced работа с unicode

Tags: perl

```
while (my $extractData = Text::Balanced::extract_tagged($Localtxt, "Если.+?Тогда", "КонецЕсли;")) {
    say "====";
    say $extractData;
}
```

Код отлично работает если читаю Localtxt инициированный в программе, если читаю из файла не работает, фиг знает почему. Сам файл в utf8, читаю тоже в utf8 пробовал читать по разному

```
open(my $F, "<", $FName) or die "Ошибка открытия $FName\n". $!;
```

и так

```
open(my $F, "<:utf8", $FName) or die "Ошибка открытия $FName\n". $!;
```

Пробовал с

```
use utf8;
```

и без. Какие-то шаманства прям нужно производить если речь заходить о юникоде. 
Например если я парс делаю регуляркой в своей программе я должен добавить /u, но в модуле balansed.pm нет /u

```
unless ($$textref =~ m/\G$ldel/gc)
```

> хотя что уж там, я пробовал добавлять, не помогло.

Именно этот unless срабатывает.

Содержимое файла:

> Если ЗначениеЗаполнено(СсылкаКорр) Тогда
>
> ОбъектКорр = СсылкаКорр.ПолучитьОбъект();
>       Если Не ЗначениеЗаполнено(РасширениеСсылок) Тогда
>         DOM = БФТ_СинхронизаторСервер.ПервичнаяСериализацияОбъекта(ОбъектКорр,
>   Неопределено, Истина);
>       Иначе
>         DOM = БФТ_СинхронизаторСервер.РасширеннаяПервичнаяСериализацияОбъекта(ОбъектКорр,
>   Неопределено, РасширениеСсылок, Неопределено, Истина);
>       КонецЕсли;   КонецЕсли; Если ОбластьДо <> Область Тогда // область была переключена
>                   Если ОбластьДо <> 0 Тогда
>                           БФТ_СерверОбластиДанных.СменитьОбластьДанных(ОбластьДо);
>                   Иначе
>                           БФТ_СерверОбластиДанных.ВыйтиИзОбластиДанных();
>                   КонецЕсли; КонецЕсли;

вот полный код

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Balanced;
use Data::Dumper;   
use utf8;
use 5.016;

binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');

local $/;
my $Localtxt = <DATA>;

my $FName = "D:\\GIT\\ObjectCoupling\\Module.bsl";
open(my $F, "<:utf8", $FName) or die "Ошибка открытия $FName\n". $!;

local $/ = "\r";
my $txt = <$F>;
close $F;

while (my $extractData = Text::Balanced::extract_tagged($txt, "Если.+?Тогда", "КонецЕсли;")) {
    say "====";
    say $extractData;

}
#say Dumper \@extractData;


__DATA__
  Если ЗначениеЗаполнено(СсылкаКорр) Тогда
    ОбъектКорр = СсылкаКорр.ПолучитьОбъект();
    Если Не ЗначениеЗаполнено(РасширениеСсылок) Тогда
      DOM = БФТ_СинхронизаторСервер.ПервичнаяСериализацияОбъекта(ОбъектКорр, Неопределено, Истина);
    Иначе
      DOM = БФТ_СинхронизаторСервер.РасширеннаяПервичнаяСериализацияОбъекта(ОбъектКорр, Неопределено, РасширениеСсылок, Неопределено, Истина);
    КонецЕсли;
  КонецЕсли; Если ОбластьДо <> Область Тогда // область была переключена
                Если ОбластьДо <> 0 Тогда
                        БФТ_СерверОбластиДанных.СменитьОбластьДанных(ОбластьДо);
                Иначе
                        БФТ_СерверОбластиДанных.ВыйтиИзОбластиДанных();
                КонецЕсли;
КонецЕсли;
```

Если использовать $Localtxt, все работает, если $txt не работает

Comment: 1) https://habr.com/post/53578/ 2) https://habr.com/post/163439/

Answer (score 0):

```
$ uname -om
x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

1)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use utf8;
use Text::Balanced;
use Encode qw/decode_utf8/;
use File::Slurp;

my $Localtxt = read_file('utf8.txt');
$Localtxt = decode_utf8($Localtxt);

while(my $extractData = Text::Balanced::extract_tagged($Localtxt, 
        'Если.+?Тогда', 'КонецЕсли;')) {
    say "====";
    say $extractData;
}
```

2)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use utf8;
use Text::Balanced;
use Path::Tiny;

my $file = path('utf8.txt');
my $Localtxt = $file->slurp_utf8;

while(my $extractData = Text::Balanced::extract_tagged($Localtxt, 
        'Если.+?Тогда', 'КонецЕсли;')) {
    say "====";
    say $extractData;
}
```

3)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use utf8;
use Text::Balanced;

open my $file, '<:utf8', 'utf8.txt';
local $/;
my $Localtxt = <$file>;
close $file;

while(my $extractData = Text::Balanced::extract_tagged($Localtxt, 
        'Если.+?Тогда', 'КонецЕсли;')) {
    say "====";
    say $extractData;
}
```

Итого, ошибки:

1) строительство велосипедов при наличии большого количества модулей (не только из пунктов 1 и 2) для чтения файла целиком, которые позволяют избегать банальных...

2) ...граблей типа этих:

```
# здесь мы задали разделитель записей (строк в данном случае):
local $/ = "\r";
# а здесь мы читаем из файла ОДНУ ЗАПИСЬ (СТРОКУ):
my $txt = <$F>;
# в результате в переменной $txt окажется не весь файл, а 
# только его часть, до первого символа \r
```

Читаем [perldoc / perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> The input record separator, newline by default. [...] You may set it
>   to a multi-character string to match a multi-character terminator,
>   **or to undef to read through the end of file**.

Comment: а чем Text::Balanced не нормальный?

Comment: Ну не работает...

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос кодом, такой же как твой 3-й вариант

Comment: @АртемАртемыч, нет, он не такой же. Попробуй вывести значение `$txt` сразу после чтения файла. Уверен, там будет совсем не то, что ожидается :) Подсказка: что делает вот эта строка `local $/ = "\r";`?

Comment: тут вы не правы, вы думаете я не попробовал вывести say $txt; в процессе выяснения проблемы? say $txt; возвращает полый текст.
Так же пробовал read_file, тоже самое

Comment: @АртемАртемыч, спорьте с кем-нибудь другим и в другом месте. Мой код работает, все три варианта. Ваш - нет. На одно отличие уже указал. Ищите разницу дальше, побуквенно.

Comment: Пожалуйста читайте все, а не начало. "Так же пробовал read_file, тоже самое", видимо не в этом дело.

Comment: Ну, подземный стук не лечится.

Answer (score 0):

Специально для **PinkTux**. Скопировал код, поменял только путь, не работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Вынесите это в вопрос, с соотвествующей пометкой "Upd".